# DJANGO ALL AUTHEMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-allauth

I am trying to have two different redirects...one for normal login and another for redirect after email confirmation

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile' 
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

But when I enable login, `AUTHENTICATED REDIRECT` goes to `LOGIN_REDIRECT` but when I disable Login it goes to the `EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_REDIRECT` route.

When I try printing the adapter settings for `email_confirmation` redirect url below it shows only the `LOGIN_REDIRECT`

```
def get_email_confirmation_redirect_url(self, request): 
    """ The URL to return to after successful e-mail confirmation. """ 

    if request.user.is_authenticated: 
     if app_settings.EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL: 
       return \ 
       app_settings.EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL 
     else: 
      return self.get_login_redirect_url(request) 
    else: 
     return app_settings.EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL
```

I tried overriding this `get_email_confirmation_redirect_url` in the adapter but still wont work. It is not picking the `REDIRECT` before I login and reverify.

Comment: When I print the user in adapter settings it shows Ananonymoususer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile'` was not working if the user is not logged in, I decided to override `DefaultAccountAdapter` in Django Allauth. My login was that if the time the user joined the app and the time logged in exceeds a certain threshold, then the redirection would be different. So I created an adapter in my users app as below:

```
class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

  def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
    expiry = 90 #seconds

    assert request.user.is_authenticated
    if (request.user.last_login - request.user.date_joined).seconds < expiry:
        url = 'profile/'
    else:
        url = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
    return resolve_url(url)
```

I then passed this adapter in my settings.py